# Canonical Q/A for people that have problems with Future<T> in [flutter]

Tags: discussion, canonical

I'm relatively new to [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter). There seems to be huge amounts of people who are starting to work with flutter and who have not heard of the `async`/`await` concepts either in flutter or in other languages (you can call it a `Task<T>` or a `Promise<T>` or a `Future<T>` but the concept is always the same).

Of any amount of questions I read, 50% seem to be about:

> I have a Future<SomeThing> and I cannot use it like a SomeThing.

I have looked for dupe targets and sometimes I found some, but often the other questions with good answers are very specific and people might not *see* that they talk about the common problem of `async`/`await` and `Future<>`, because one might focus on `SharedPreferences` another one on a REST call, a third one on a database or FireStore call and the abstraction, that it's basically all the same, might not be reachable for someone who has no experience with this topic.

So before I write one myself, my question is:

Did I miss a canonical post for this? Is there some Q/A I *should* be using as a dupe target?

Comment: I would hope there is a duplicate for that. For the JavaScript tag we have two canonical duplicates for using promises (closest thing to futures) and asynchronous code in general. Both are very comprehensive and save a ton of explanations that are needed multiple times a day. I am not familiar with Flutter but I would certainly hope you have a similar canonical for that. If not, it might be time to either elect one or make one.

Comment: I created one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it). Feel free to improve as necessary.